# How to Apply GPO through WMI filtering

Tags: active-directory

I want to apply a GPO in such a way that all the users in the domain whose department is "catering" should get affected by it. Should I use ***WMI filtering*** or is there any other way to filter like this.

And I used this query to filter --
select * from Win32_ComputerSystem where department='catering'

Comment: You asked: "Should i use WMI filtering or is there any other way to filter like this." And you've had several answers saying that you shouldn't use WMI and you should use security groups. I'm not sure why you are so stuck on WMI still..

Answer (score 3):

Catering sounds like a nice easy way to group machines / users, so in this instance, I would suggest that it would be much more transparent and maintainable to apply this to a Catering OU (Or OU's) or a Catering security group.

Leave WMI filters for when you have no choice. In my experience, they're rarely used because there is *generally* a better way forward.

Comment: I cannot shift all the users to the OU or add them to another group. So I am choosing WMI filtering. Please provide me the syntax for doing it

Comment: Why can't you add them to a security group? This is how Microsoft recommends you do it. You clearly asked if there is a better way and I'm telling you the right way(s).

Comment: ServerFault (and StackExchange) are not for "please provide teh codez" questions.

Comment: I cannot add all the created users to that group. Also I have to add all the users that i m gonna create to the group. SO querying seems much easier for me

Comment: No, it's terrible - just add the users to the group. It's not a complicated process and it's how all other organisations manage it. It doesn't matter if you have thousands of users in that group, it's fine.

Comment: Okay let me redefine my question. I am curious to know the query for it. Atleast now can you provide me the querry?

Comment: @user2010392 I know you obviously want to do things the way you "sort of know" because that seems easier than learning something new... but there also comes a point where you've worked so hard at stretching a concept further than it was supposed to go that you might just as well have done things properly in the first place. It would be less work and you'll end up with a more robust system afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a programmer so don't take what I say below as gospel, you should check over at SO if you want confirmation, but I can't find a single WMI property for department that you can use to filter off of:

[image]

The CLOSEST I can find in the WMI namespace are the Win32_NetworkLoginProfile or Win32_UserAccount but they don't have a DEPARTMENT property in its class.

**IF your GPO is using GPPs you can set up an LDAP query and do selective GPP targeting using that query:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753205.aspx**

Other than that...Dan's choice works.

Comment: Me too din't find anything !

Comment: Edited my answer...

Comment: +1 for the LDAP query on GPP - forgot about those..

Comment: How to use those LDA queries in the Gpo. Could you please explain Rex. Where to give that query?

Comment: Does the GPO use GPPs to apply the settings you are talking about?  If not, then it can't be used.  If so, then look here on how to use it:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733022.aspx and http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/netgeneral/Group-Policy-Preferences-Top-5-Item-Level-Targeting-Options.html  and then open a new question if you can't get it working with details on the GPO/GPP and what you tried.