# Adding properties to the Win32_UserAccount Class

Tags: active-directory, wmi

How to add new properties to ***Win32_UserAccount*** class and add values to it? I have used wbemtest command and Have created a new property to the class Win32_UserAccount. How to make it fetch the values from the user's attribute. For Example I have created a new property named Department. It should fetch the values from the user's department attribute value . How can I do it?

Comment: We've discussed this here: http://serverfault.com/questions/519016/how-to-apply-gpo-through-wmi-filtering

Comment: What you're doing is silly, hard to support and makes life deliberately hard work for yourself. Please learn the correct (And far easier way) to achieve what you want. I'm not joking when I say you'd have had this working by now.

Comment: It may be the easiest way. I am learning it now. What if in the future WMI is the only way. I cant be Learning it that time. Jus comment if u know how to do it through WMI

Comment: Truth is, I'm not even sure what you want is possible and neither are other people. This is because it never comes up as WMI is seen as a way to solve more abstract issues - such as applying policies to a specific operating system. It's powerful, for sure, but in 10 years I've barely seen it implemented in a Group Policy context. And **never** for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then for what reason MS has added that option. There should be some cause. Whats wrong in learning it? I am almost near to it. But need some assistance.

Comment: They added it for edge cases - what you're doing is simply routine, day to day group policy and it's *exactly* what Security Groups and Organisational Units were made for.